# Firebase Chat change reference with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying out how to incorporate firebase with angular in such a way that the user is able to change the "Channel" of the chat via selecting from a dropdownlist.

This is the code that I have at the moment:

Note: The channel attribute is defined in another portion of code, and the entire page is loaded only once.

```
app.controller('mychat', function($scope, $firebaseArray) {

    var d = new Date();
    var today = d.getDate()+d.getMonth()+d.getYear();
    var txt = document.getElementById('txtFBMsgs'); //store id of textbox

    //Query

    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child(channel)

    $scope.fbmessages = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.send = function() {
        if (txt.value != ""){   //check if textbox contains any message
            $scope.fbmessages.$add({
                sender: sender,
                message: $scope.messageText,
                date: Date.now()
            })

            txt.value = ""; //reset value of textbox
        }
    }
})
```

and here is my html portion:

```
<div class="card mb-1 col-md-3" ng-controller="mychat" id="myDiv">
    <div class="card-body" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y:scroll; min-height:60vh; max-height:64vh;">
        <div>
            <p ng-repeat="m in fbmessages"> {{m.date | date:'short'}} - {{m.sender}}: <br> {{m.message}}</p>            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-9">
            <input type="text" id = "txtFBMsgs" class="form-control" placeholder="Message here..." ng-model="messageText" onkeydown = "if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('sendBtn').click()">
        </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" id="sendBtn" ng-click="send()">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

basically, it is a div that displays the chat messages, and an input box which is able to send the message to firebase.

Can I change the 'Channel' dynamically via javascript, such as on an onchange in a DDL?